# VBA code to auto update PowerPoint links to Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint, office-2013

I have hundreds of PowerPoint presentations that all have linked Word objects in them.  How can I auto-update all of the links without opening each presentation?  I'm assuming it'll be done with VBA, but the only VBA examples I can find are for auto-updating linked Excel objects.  I'm not familiar enough with VBA to modify the code.

Ultimately, I'd like to run this via Command Prompt.

Using PowerPoint & Word 2013.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show what you have tried so far and put your code in your question. SO is not a place to request code to be made but to get answers to a problem or error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

DragonSamu's right ... but to get you started, try this from within PPT itself, then work out how to rewrite it in a scripting language or something that will compile to an EXE

For each file you want to process, open the file (via code) then

```
Call UpdateLinks(ActivePresentation)


Sub UpdateLinks(oPres As Presentation)

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In oPres.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                oSh.LinkFormat.Update
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```